# Multiple greps in pipeline not terminating after completion

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm seem to be having a problem with a simple `grep` statement not finishing/terminating after it's been completed.

For example:

```
 grep -v -E 'syslogd [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}: restart' |
 grep -v 'printStats: total reads from cache:' /var/log/customlog.log >\
 /tmp/filtered_log.tmp
```

The above statement will strip out the contents and save them into a temp file, however after the `grep` finishes processing the entire file, the shell script hangs and cannot proceed anymore. This behavior is also triggered when manually running the command within the command line. Essentially combining multiple grep statements causes a PAGER like action (`more`/`less`).

Does anyone have any suggestions to overcome this limitation? Ideally I wouldn't want to do the following giving that the `customlog.log` file might get huge at times.

```
cat /var/log/customlog.log |
grep -v -E 'syslogd [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}: restart' |
grep -v 'printStats: total reads from cache:' > /tmp/filtered_log.tmp
```

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: You need to move the `/var/log/customlog.log` parameter to the *first* grep command on the line. Your command is hanging because this grep is waiting for input from the console. You want the first grep to process the file, and then pass its reduced output to the second grep instance.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that completely answers my question. -Tony

Answer (score 3):

As explained above, you need to move here your file name:

```
grep -v -E \
    'syslogd [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}: restart' /var/log/customlog.log
| grep -v 'printStats: total reads from cache:' > /tmp/filtered_log.tmp
```

But you can also combine the two greps:

```
grep -v -E \
    -e 'syslogd [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}: restart' \
    -e  'printStats: total reads from cache:' /var/log/customlog.log > \
    /tmp/filtered_log.tmp
```

Saves a bit of CPU and will fix your error at the same time.

BTW, another possible issue: What if two instances of this script are run at the same time? Both will be using the same temp file. This probably isn't an issue in this particular case, but you might as well get used to developing scripts for that situation. I recommend that you use `$$` to put the process ID in your temporary file:

```
tempFileName="/tmp/filtered_log.$$.tmp"
grep -v -E -e [blah... blah.. blah] /var/log/customlog.log > $tempFileName
```

Now, if two different people are running this process, you won't get them using the same temp file.

---

## Appended

As pointed out by [uwe-kleine-konig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/578907/uwe-kleine-konig), you're actually better off using [mktemp](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mktemp):

```
tempFileName=$(mktemp filtered_log.XXXXX)
grep -v -E -e [blah... blah.. blah] /var/log/customlog.log > $tempFileName
```

Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: still better use `mktemp` to assert nobody guessed your pid and placed a symlink with the corresponding name.

Comment: Good idea although I never used it. From the manpage: Many shell scripts take the name of the program with the pid as a suffix and use that as a temporary file name.  This kind of naming scheme is predictable and the race condition it creates is easy for an attacker to win. To use mktemp, you have to do this: `myTempFile=$(mktemp foo.XXXXXX)`.